# Taking in a file and removing the duplicates within the file

Tags: c++, file, sorting, io

I have a comma separated file that is of extension .csv and the terms look like this:

```
30,Movies,53808-0776,278,65.75
31,Beauty,48951-8130,725,83.42
32,Baby,59779-224,848,82
33,Industrial,55711-070,753,46.48
34,Industrial,76446-002,272,89.03
35,Sports,68151-2870,185,2.86
36,Toys,0245-0709,783,45.65
37,Games,49999-963,523,93.65 
38,Beauty,52125-508,500,2.38
39,Toys,54092-381,783,45.65
40,Beauty,55154-6649,666,79.52
41,Jewelry,57664-327,46,10.28
42,Grocery,49738-453,317,29
```

What I need my program to do is to take in any generic file of this format, get rid of the duplicates, and then create a new file of the same extension without the duplicates. The user types in the exact location where the file is. I am using a class to hold a single data record. This is what I have so far for my header.

```
#ifndef RECORD_H_
#define RECORD_H_
#include <iostream>

class Record {
public:
// Constructor
    std::Record(string department, string item_code, int quantity, double cost);
// Deconstructor
    virtual ~Record();
// Overloaded '==' and '<' Comparision Methods
    friend bool operator ==(const Record &a, const Record &b);
    friend bool operator <(const Record&, const Record&);
// Overloaded '<<' Operator
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const Record&);
// Private Member Functions
private:
    std::string department;
    std::string item_code;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
};
#endif /* RECORD_H_ */
```

The files are all small, so simple sorting methods work. I am confused on these aspects. Do I do the act of storing an object in the vector in the source code or do I need to create a definition for that? Also, if I take in a file, how do I get the program to create a new file in the same extension? (.csv)

Comment: The .csv you have mentioned rows are not identical ... Which column you need to check for duplicate

Comment: I am confused with what exactly you mean but, in the snippet I provided, Industrial appears twice. (The titles that repeat will not always be in sequential order.) I just need to check the title of each object that I create.

Comment: Look into C++ `<map>`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ The map's key is the title, the key's value is everything else in the row for that key.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I already defined functions to compare values. The problem is actually using those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assumint that you have a class the `Record` described in your question with a defined `operator==` and you have a vector of these that you read into memory from your csv file, you can do something like this to remove duplicates using the algorithms library:

```
std::vector<Record> records; // full of Record

// rearranges the vector, moving all the unique elements to the front
// and duplicates to the back
// last is an iterator to beginning of the duplicates
auto last = std::unique(records.begin(), records.end());

// erase all duplicates
records.erase(last, records.end());
```

Note `std::unique` will use your defined `operator==` in `Record`.